# Hiding the IP and Port of Shoutcast streaming

Tags: javascript, php, flash, shoutcast

We have a Shoutcast webradio, hosted on server A.

We also have a Drupal CMS on server B elsewhere -- this site embeds the Flash Player, which streams the feed.

We managed to hide the IP and Port (server A) of the stream from the HTML source code (server B) with some script testing a condition before pushing the real Header Location (of server A), but some browsers such as Firefox displays the final stream's IP in the Status bar, when contacting the feed.

Is it possible to completely hide the IP and Port of the stream from showing at all, on every browser?

Maybe changing from Flash to HTML5 player?
Or doing some Htaccess Rewrite??

Comment: why do you need to hide the IP address?

Comment: to avoid the stream getting stolen and played elsewhere - we have ads showing around the player.

Comment: You are going to need to change your implementation then to something that offers protected streaming

Comment: Like what? Another streaming service? Auth with login/pass? Stream aliases?  I just drop terms here but I don't know much, that's why I ask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding the address of the server doesn't help you.  Even if you were to put a proxy out in front, now the users can simply connect to the proxy server.  You must offer an endpoint your clients can connect to, and this is the same endpoint that can be used elsewhere.

What you really want to do is check that the request for the stream originates on your page and not someone else's.  SHOUTcast itself doesn't offer this functionality.

Depending on how your player is set up, you might wish to simply check the `Referer:` header.  Usually, this will contain the domain of your site.  Server-side, you can check to see if it does.  If it doesn't, you can reject access.

Another method is to issue a session token that is only good for one use by one user.  You can then include it in the stream request query string, like `/your/stream?token=0123456789abcdef`.  This is what you must do if your player doesn't pass a `Referer:` header, and can also be used to authenticate streams outside of your page.  (I know you aren't doing this now, but it may come in handy when you start building mobile apps and what not.)

Unfortunately, I don't know of any HTTP progressive streaming server software other than my own (AudioPump Server) that implements these methods, and AudioPump Server isn't generally available yet.  If you're interested in trying it out, you can contact brad@audiopump.co.  Otherwise, you are probably going to have to write some custom code for this.

You might also be able to finagle [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) into doing the referrer for you if you get crafty with the configuration.  Unfortunately, SHOUTcast isn't compliant with HTTP, so that may make this difficult.

Comment: The part about checking the referer is already coded -- but once a person access the page ONCE and get the stream by a "legit" way, then browsers like Firefox will also give the IP and Port in the status bar, so the stream can be stolen.  Basically, the protection is only valid for the first listening, afterward the "private" stream data is displayed and can be streamed elsewhere than from the webradio site...

Comment: @ecchymose That's not what I'm suggesting.  I'm saying that you need to check the referrer for the stream data itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can only truly hide the IP by using a proxy between `A` and `B`

Comment: They aren't really interested in hiding the IP address, as much as they are interested in protecting the way the content can be consumed.  Proxying doesn't fix that problem, even though the question title is asking for it.